# Can the outcome of the submitted position be clearly determined?

Tags: analysis

Playing a blitz game, I reached the below position:

```
[Title "White to move"]
[fen "1r3rk1/1q1nbpp1/p1n1p2p/P1p1P2P/2Pp1BN1/5BP1/1P2QP2/R3R1K1 w - - 0 1"]
```

At this point both players had less then a minute, so I played `b4`. My idea was to slow down Black counterplay on the queenside, in order to get time for my attack ( `...cxb4` is the only move ). My opponent blundered and lost on time.

I do not have an engine available at the moment, hence this post. I want to know the following:

Does White have winning advantage in the above position, or Black, or is it a draw ?

I seek concrete lines and moves. You can use engines if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the original position, Stockfish doesn't see a whole lot going on. I don't think this means the game is drawn, but simply that there's no knock-out. Stockfish scores the position as slightly in White's favor. This "ideal" continuation doesn't seem suitable for a blitz game; there's too much moving for the time allowed.

I then ran the b4 move which yields a small advantage to Black. But holy smokes look at the "final" position. Black has two deadly outside connected passed pawns while While surely has a devastating King attack in there somewhere. I'll let this grind while I go to work...

```
[FEN "1r3rk1/1q1nbpp1/p1n1p2p/P1p1P2P/2Pp1BN1/5BP1/1P2QP2/R3R1K1 w - - 0 1"]

1.Qe4 (1.b4 cxb4 2.Bxh6 Qc7 3.Bf4 Kh8 4.Bxc6 Qxc6 5.Rad1 Nc5 6.Rxd4 Nb3 7.Rd3 Nxa5 8.h6 g5 9.Bc1 Nxc4 10.Nh2 Rg8 11.Red1 Rbd8 12.Rxd8 Bxd8 13.Rd4 Nb6 14.Bd2 a5 15.Qd3 Nd5 16.Ng4 Qb7 17.Qe4 b3  {-.59}) Nd8 2.Qxb7 Nxb7 3.Bc6 Rfd8 4.Bd2 Nf8 5.Be4 Rd7 6.b3 Nd8 7.Ra3 Rc7 8.f4 Nc6 9.Kg2 Nd7 10.Nf2 Nb4 11.Raa1 Rcc8 12.Reb1 Bf8 13.Ra4 Nc6 14.Nd3 f6 15.exf6 Nxf6 16.Bf3 Bd6 17.Ra3 Kf7 18.Raa1 Kg8 19.Rb2 Kf7 20.g4 Nd7 21.Re1 Nf6 22.Rbb1 {+.34}
```

ALNS, if you have specific variations, let me know and I'll run them.

EDIT - Here's the analysis of `1.b4` after something like 10 hours. This is coming down to a draw. I don't think Black can convert this.

```
[FEN "1r3rk1/1q1nbpp1/p1n1p2p/P1p1P2P/2Pp1BN1/5BP1/1P2QP2/R3R1K1 w - - 0 1"]

1.b4 cxb4 2.Rad1 Qc7 3.Bxc6 Qxc6 4.Rxd4 b3 5.Nxh6+ gxh6 6.Bxh6 f5 7.exf6 Bxf6 8.Rg4+ Kf7 9.Qd3 b2 10.Rb1 Ke7 11.Bxf8+ Rxf8 12.Rf4 Qd6 13.Qxd6+ Kxd6 14.Rxf6 Nxf6 15.Rxb2 Nxh5 16.Rb6+ Ke7 17.Rxa6 Nf6 18.Ra7+ Nd7 19.Kg2 Rc8 20.g4 Rxc4 21.Kg3 Kd6 22.f4 e5 23.fxe5+ Nxe5 24.g5 Rg4+ 25.Kf2 Rxg5 26.a6 Rg4 27.Ra8 Ra4 28.Ke2 Ra3 29.a7 Nc6 30.Kd1 Nxa7 {-.49 after 34541 seconds}
```

```
[title "Try Be4 Bb1"]
[FEN "1r3rk1/1q1nbpp1/p1n1p2p/P1p1P2P/2Pp1BN1/5BP1/1P2QP2/R3R1K1 w - - 0 1"]

1.b4 cxb4 2.Be4 Nc5 {Stockfish initially tried a few variations on 3.Bxh6 but rejected them. Instead Stockfish goes defensive} 3.Bg2 (3. Bb1 d3 4.Qd1 b3 5.Be3 Rfd8 6.Qf3 Qb4 7.Rd1 b2 8.Ra2 Nd4 9.Bxd4 Rxd4 10.Ne3 Ne4 11.Kg2 Nc3 12.Rxd3 Rxd3 13.Rxb2 Qxb2 14.Bxd3 Bc5 15.Ng4 Rd8 16.Bf1 Qa1 17.Bd3 Qa2 18.Bf1 Qxa5 19.Qc6 Bd4 20.c5 Nd5 21.Qxa6 Qxc5 22.Bd3 {-5.65 White is a rook down.}
) Rfc8 4.Rad1 Qd7 5.Bxh6 gxh6 6.Qd2 Qe8 7.Nxh6+ Kg7 8.Qf4 b3 9.Bxc6 Rxc6 10.Rxd4 b2 11.Rb1 Nb3 12.Rxb2 Nxd4 13.Rxb8 Ne2+ 14.Kf1 Nxf4 15.Rxe8 Bb4 16.gxf4 Kxh6 17.Rh8+ Kg7 18.Ra8 Bd2 19.Ke2 Bxf4 20.Ra7 Bxe5 21.Kd3 Bf4 22.Ra8 {-2.29}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for: a comprehensive analysis. I have upvoted, but will wait for your analysis of `b4` to end. I think that currently, your analysis offers winning chances for Black, so maybe `b4` was a mistake... I guess in the strongest continuation Black is slightly better, or it is completely equal. I am surprised to be honest, because I had so many pieces at the kingside that I thought I should break through somehow... After `b4`  I was `Be4 + Bb1 + Qe4`, I wonder if you can somehow analyse that plan? Thanks anyway...

Answer (score 1):

This is what I like to use Lichess for

http://en.lichess.org/analysis/standard/1r3rk1/1q1nbpp1/p1n1p2p/P1p1P2P/2Pp1BN1/5BP1/1P2QP2/R3R1K1

It's not nearly as powerful as stockfish or the likes but you can get a general idea whether you had particularly strong tactics available.

According to the analysis it sees an opportunity for a draw through perpetuals by sacrificing the bishop on H6 but no particular advantages to either side to play for. It favors Qd4 which does centralize the queen and puts some pressure on the knight on c6 but overal it's very even.

Comment: I saw nothing on the link you provided. Do I have to be registered member in order to see the analysis?

Comment: I edited my link, otherwise use the analysis option(under tools) and paste the position in the FEN string.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.
You would need to play it out to the end to be sure.

And even then there would be questions like what if at move 77  I did this move instead of that move.

Even engines would not be definitive.  But if you played the position out a thousand times between two engines you could get a statistical answer but still not likely to be definitive like the OP implied.

That said, my intuition says white could win and should at least draw.  OTB especially blitz ,I would be trying for that mate and expecting a perpetual at worse.

I would play Q-Q2  (qd2 for the kiddies:)  and look at the bishop taking the king rook pawn followed by Be4.  Black might  play P-KB4
[Pf4] to hold on but his position would not be as good and white could ultimately win.